# how to add a word after specific patterns into a file linux

Tags: linux, sed

I have around 3000 files (phylogenetic tree files) in which there are some specific genes that I want to insert **{Foreground}** after **:** .

For instance;

```
(CBREN_CBREN.CBN09275:0.1505047394,((((((CBREN_CBREN.CBN30237:0.1134434184,CDOUG_CDOUG.g12077.t1:0.1229043127)92:0.0214649873,(CTRO_Csp11.Scaffold630.g17672.t1:0.0631318986,CWALLA_CWALL.g8382.t1:0.0753910535)92:0.0239057141)93:0.0325662116,((CBRI_CBG17629:0.0312071500,CNIGO_CNIGO.Cni-ugt-54:0.0736951024)99:0.0494942769,(CSINI_CSINI.Csp5_scaffold_00095.g4122.t1:0.0606700444,(CTRIBU_CTRIB.g6645.t1:0.0736535896,CZANZI_CZANZ.g13363.t1:0.0688400206)58:0.0091500887)100:0.0582326665)83:0.0238218345)64:0.0211630102,(CLAT_CLATE.FL83_14023:0.0101547146,CREMA_CREMA.FL82_03023:0.0239757985)100:0.0954119437)99:0.0555252013,(CELE_T25B9.7:0.1602734533,CINO_Sp34_40094810.t1:0.2305325582)93:0.0423976759)99:0.1230996301,(CJPJ_00498800.t1:0.0895372175,CJPJ_00700900.t1:0.1411739758)100:0.1285915300)100:0.8994859943,(((((((CBRI_CBG13049:0.0452507889,CNIGO_CNIGO.Cnig_chr_II.g5360.1:0.0660490258)68:0.0042384566,CNIGO_CNIGO.Cnig_chr_II.g5361.1:0.0321380678)100:0.0949970282,(CSINI_CSINI.Csp5_scaffold_00169.g6176.t1:0.0626931406,CZANZI_CZANZ.g6858.t1:0.0894503797)100:0.0715162764)100:0.0539156634,(CLAT_CLATE.FL83_09404:0.0252696400,CREMA_CREMA.FL82_14428:0.0155270060)100:0.0771958234)73:0.0198698760,CELE_T03D3.1:0.2195730426)85:0.0368288871,CDOUG_CDOUG.g745.t1:0.1814046140)65:0.0156158577,CWALLA_CWALL.g18942.t1:0.1591453045)78:0.0306577438);
```

What I need is to include {Foreground} before **:** of each CELE..., CBRI.. and CTRO..

For instance,

```
CTRO_Csp11.Scaffold630.g17672.t1{Foreground}:0.0631318986
CELE_T03D3.1{Foreground}:0.2195730426
CBRI_CBG17629{Foreground}:0.0312071500
```

in one file for these tree matches. and one by one as separete files.

I tried

```
cat OG0000733.tree |sed -e 's/CINO_Sp34_........\.t1/&{Foreground}/g' > edited.tree
```

but number of character is different after **_** for each gene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sed -E 's/(CELE|CBRI|CTRO)[^:]*/&{Foreground}/g' OG0000733.tree > edited.tree
```

The `(CELE|CBRI|CTRO)[^:]*` expression finds `CELE`, `CBRI` or `CTRO` and then any zero or more characters other than a colon.

Replacement is the whole matched text (`&`) and a `{Foreground}` string.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `.` by something that repeats any number of times, but never reaches too far. It seems it could be a colon:

```
CINO_Sp34_[^:]*\.t1
```